# Why is the holding of Chakra different in different images of Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, weapon, symbolism, sudarsana

[image][image]

In northern parts of India, Sri Vishnu holds Sudarshana Chakra on His forefinger. But in the Southern parts of India, He is seen holding the chakra within two fingers (as seen in the enclosed images).

Is there any scriptural basis for this difference?

Comment: Vishnu's chakras holding position has large yogic meaning is what I heard but couldnt find scriptural reference for it to answer here

Comment: @AkshayS No yogic meaning or anything in both the images there. It is just a way of depiction of the artist there. One image is in rest position where Shankha and Chakra are not used in war. Another is when he uses them during the war. Second image is inaccurate because when Lord came to rescue elephant Gajendra, the Sudarshana and Panchajanya was ready and not in resting position. BTW, Partha, the source of the 1st image? It is Vishwaksena Perumal image from Wikipedia. Are you sure it is Vishnu's image you uploaded? Which image is south and which is north?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma thats from net.But i have so many images of Sri Vishnu in my collection.Most show it holding on forefinger.The Guruvayur images shows holding it by entire hand.And South indian images within two fingers.If its a circlular discuss, how can it be held within two fingers--this Q also arises in my mind

Comment: @Sarvabhouma you are an expert on Sri Vishnu and hope will be able to throw some light.Thanks:)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma There's yogic meaning in entire Vishnu's posture, images on holding chakras in his hand etc.... its those knowledge are revealed mostly to disciples and not open.